# sweepprivkey alternative - bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoind, private-key, spending

I guess they took off this function, so any alternative?

what i'm looking to do is exactly like this

sweepprivkey privkey minconfirms [destinationtype destination] [fee] [amount changeaddress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody "took off" this function, [it was only proposed](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Sweepprivkey_proposal), but was never actually added to Bitcoin Core.

Instead, you can use `importprivkey` and then send BTC to a new address:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:How_to_import_private_keys_in_Bitcoin_Core_0.7%2B

Note:

- [Why doc says importing private keys is so dangerous?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29948/why-doc-says-importing-private-keys-is-so-dangerous)
- [Why so many warnings about importing private keys?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18619/why-so-many-warnings-about-importing-private-keys)

Comment: how to send just imported BTC directly to specific address?